# What would you call a function that returns an approximation of a number at intervals of fixed magnitude?

Tags: functions

Is there a name for the following type of function:

$f_a: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

$f_a(x) = a \Big \lfloor \frac{x}{a} \Big\rfloor$

If you were to plot this, it would look like stairs. But it's more useful if you think a situation like:

$g_a(x) = f_a(h(x))$

with for example:

$a = \frac{1}{10}$, $h(x) = cos(x)$

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to have a name.  And you need to clarify what $f(x,0)$ might be.

Comment: I edited a bit hopefully to be clearer. $f(x,0)$ would be undefined, though obv. as a approaches zero f(x) should approach x.

Comment: It's not a standard term, but I might call it a "discretization", or "discrete approximation".

Comment: Those are called "step functions". More generally, a step function is any function $f$ that takes on only countably many values (i.e., there is some sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ such that for all $x$ there is some $n$ with $f(x) = a_n$). For example, such functions are used in defining Lebesgue integration, where the sets $f^{-1}(a_n)$ are required to be measurable. First the integrals of step functions are defined as $\int f\,d\mu = \sum_n a_n\mu(f^{-1}(a_n))$, then the integrals of other functions are defined by $\int gd\mu = \sup \{\int fd\mu \mid f \le g \text{ is a step function}\}$.